# Drupal 7: grayscale image to colored at mouse-hover. image generated with ImageStyles

Tags: image, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-modules

I have a list of client logos (Views Block) at frontpage. Images are generated via ImageStyle (resize and desaturate). So the logos are grayscale, but I need them to be colored at mousehover. Any idea how to do that?

I googled if there is a way to make image grayscale with css, but cant find it. or I cant find a way to make 2 different image (one colored, one grayscale) in a ImageStyle.

Helps are much appreciated! Thanks a lot your time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set up two ImageStyles, both with the same dimensions.

One is the regular, colour image, the other the filtered one. The settings should be the same (cropping etc.), except that one has the desaturation filter. You can call one setting 'logo-thumb-normal' and one 'logo-thumb-filtered'

You should now have two output images which are the same except for the filtering, and they should have the same file name, though they will be in different folders.

Set your content type Image field to use 'logo-thumb-filtered.'

So, when you upload an image within a content type, that should generate two files, one for each setting:

`/sites/default/files/styles/logo-thumb-normal/public/field/image/image.jpg` and
`/sites/default/files/styles/logo-thumb-filtered/public/field/image/image.jpg`

You can refer to these two images manually, as Spudley suggests, but even easier may be to use jQuery to swap the images out on hover (here's a simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/vSUkv/1/):

```
$('.image1').hover(
    function () {
        src = $(this).attr('src');
        $(this).attr('src', src.replace('filtered', 'normal'));
    }, 
    function () {
        $(this).attr('src', src.replace('normal', 'filtered'));
    }
);
```

**EDIT:**

To include jQuery in Drupal 7:

To add the script above, you can:

- Add a custom JavaScript file to your theme, if you haven't already, by adding the line `scripts[] js/custom.js` to your theme's `info` file.
- Create the `js` folder inside your theme, and create the `custom.js` file inside that folder.
- Add the following code to your `custom.js` file:

---

```
// We define a function that takes one parameter named $.
(function ($) {
// Store our function as a property of Drupal.behaviors
  Drupal.behaviors.imageSwap = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
         $('.hplogoclient a img').hover(
         function () {
            src = $(this).attr('src');
            $(this).attr('src', src.replace('filtered', 'normal'));
         }, 
         function () {
            $(this).attr('src', src.replace('normal', 'filtered'));
         }
       );
    }
  }
}(jQuery));
```

- Clear the cache and check again. See http://drupal.org/node/171213 for details.

Comment: Hi @g_thom ! Thanks for super detailed post! it works great at jsfiddle.net example, even when I replace my actual paths and class names. but it just doesnt work in my actual page :( maybe conflict with a different script at the page! trying to solve! it gives this error https://img.skitch.com/20110801-85wdfigmu6dgtgrabd2ks3ij45.png

Comment: Hi @Drupal guy - I've updated my answer to go through how I added the jQuery function successfully. Let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: you are a life saver person!! I appreciate your time on this!!! it works just great!!! I learnt a new thing from you today! THANKS A LOT!!! ps any chance you pass me your contact info? I need a reliable developer for some projects

Comment: Glad it worked for you! Sure, I'd be happy to talk - is there an email I can reach you at or another way to contact you?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to need two images for this; one for the greyscale version and one for the colour version. You can't easily do that kind of image manipulation on the browser at the moment. (in fact, it *can* be done if you really want to, using some of the more modern browser features, but it'd probably be a lot more work, and would not be compatible in all browsers, so I'd stick with the two image solution for now)

For the two-image solution, if you set your image as a background image, then it's fairly simple in CSS:

```
.myelement {
    background-image:url(/path/to/greyscale.png);
 }

.myelement:hover {
    background-image:url(/path/to/fullcolour.png);
}
```

You could also do it using CSS 'Sprites', which basically means having both pictures in a single image file, but setting the element's size such that only the appropriate part of the image is visible; then in the `:hover` styles, adjust the offset so that the other part of the image is visible instead.

It's a bit more fiddly to set up CSS sprites than simply using two separate images, but it can be worth the effort. Find out more about how to do it and why here: http://css-tricks.com/158-css-sprites/

Comment: Thanks for your time @Spudley , the way you mention is good and easy to make in a single html/css, but my main point is how to make this with drupal (ImageStyle, Views)

Answer (score 0):

There is a very easy solution using only simple HTML and CSS:

HTML:

```
<div id="desaturate"> <a href="/thelink"> <a img src="/sites/default/files/images/yourfolders/image.png" alt="this image is">
```

CSS:

```
#desaturate img { opacity:0.4; padding-left: 20px; } #desaturate img:hover { opacity:1.0; }
```

Here is a [sample and simple tutorial](http://www.burofriesen.nl/en/desaturated-image-becomes-regular-image-hover-only-simple-css).

Answer (score 0):

You can now do this in CSS, see http://www.karlhorky.com/2012/06/cross-browser-image-grayscale-with-css.html :

```
.myimage:hover {
  filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); /* Firefox 10+, Firefox on Android */
  filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Chrome 19+, Safari 6+, Safari 6+ iOS */
}

.myimage {
  filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'1 0 0 0 0, 0 1 0 0 0, 0 0 1 0 0, 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
}
```

This saves having to generate, store and load 2 images.